# Angular 4 - ngIf with FormGroup controls

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

So it would be great if I could access the FormGroup control values from within the template to conditionally show fields like this:

```
<ion-item *ngIf="profileForm.controls['gender'].value === 'female'">
```

And here is the form control:

```
<ion-select formControlName="gender"> ...
```

But I get an error: 
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

I think its a syntax issue but any help appreciated.

Comment: Please share your ts code.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do this is by adding a check using safe navigation operator

```
 <span *ngIf="profileForm.controls.gender?.value?.length > 0">
  <ion-item *ngIf="profileForm.controls['gender'].value === 'female'">
</span>
```